# Session raise an invisible catch?

Tags: c#, .net, session

This is my code:

```
public partial class context_userpanel_IoSocial : iUserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["oom-user"] = "utente";

        if ((UserOOM)Session["oom-user"] == null)
        {
            Response.Write("not logged");
        }

        Response.Write("logged");
    }
}
```

the object in `Session["oom-user"]` is of type `UserOOM`. But if I store in session a string, I don't see any `Response.Write`. Why this? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Is the string `"utente"` of type `UserOOM`? No. Then you need to fix the `if`: `if (Session["oom-user"] == null) ...`

Comment: @TimSchmelter maybe he defined an impicit cast from `string` to `UserOOM`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't see any `Response.Write` because the cast to `UserOOM` fails with a runtime exception that takes down the application.

If you want to store different types of data in the same session variable (which is perhaps not the best idea) you will have to use `is`/`as` instead of a straight cast when taking them out, for example:

```
if (Session["oom-user"] is UserOOM)
{
    // something 
}
else if (Session["oom-user"] is string)
{
    // something else
}
```

Comment: "...a runtime exception that takes down the application." - well terminates the current request anyway...

Comment: @Joe: Well sure, it doesn't take down the whole application server with it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

> the object in `Session["oom-user"]` is of type `UserOOM`.

Not from your code:

```
 Session["oom-user"] = "utente";
```

This will put a `string` in `Session["oom-user"]` and make the type-cast fail with an exception.

Comment: Maybe he defined an impicit cast from `string` to `UserOOM`?

Comment: @markzzz you could cast with `as` then there is no exception raised but the result will be null if it is not able to be casted

Comment: You can put a try/catch in this method or implement the general exception event in global.asax.... It's not clear what you want to happen here.

Answer (score 0):

Is the string `"utente"` of type `UserOOM`? No.

You need to fix the `if` clause, you don't need to cast at all if you just want to check if it's `null`:

```
    Session["oom-user"] = "utente";
    if (Session["oom-user"] == null)
    {
        Response.Write("not logged");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("logged");
    }
```

This kind of "authentication" is obviously not very safe :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not the `Session` object the one that raises the invisible exception, and the exception is not invisible.

Picture this: You have a variable of type object, and it stores a string.

```
object variable = "Test";
```

Using the `convert` operator, you then cast its value to an incompatible type 
(which is not `string` or a subclass of `string`, but `string` is a sealed type so just `string` would've worked):

```
SomeOtherClass asAstring = (SomeOtherClass)variable;
```

That fails with `InvalidCastException` as oposed to what the `as` operator does:

```
SomeOtherClass thisWillBeNUll = variable as SomeOtherClass;
```

So you see, it is not the `Session` object that throws the exception.
When you write

```
if ((SomeClass)Session["somekey"] == null) { ... }
```

you're actually writing:

```
object thisIsOk = Session["somekey"]; // this is not the throwing place
SomeClass temp = (SomeClass)thisIsOk; // this is the throwing place

// and you won't be reaching any code until the closest `catch` clause up the stack
if (temp == null) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    object obj = Session["oom-user"];
    if (obj is UserOOM)
    {
        Response.Write("logged in");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("not logged in");
    }
}
```